# problem with lazy loading in android

Tags: android, listview

i have done lazy loading in my one of activity 
lazy loading is running perfectly but first time when my screen the second and third position of list is empty but when i scroll the list all items are listing completly in list

i attached screenshot
Please give me some advice!  [This is the screen when Activity is loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkmlE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is because, you are downloading the images in a separate thread. So it will eventually take time to download images one by one. And as the thread download's your images one by one it will update your ListView with the downloaded images. This is the concept of Lazyloading. And as they are being downloaded you are storing it in a cache directory too(if I am right). So unless your image is downloaded you will not be able to see a image in your ListView which is a known fact.